# Proguard error while generating Secure Signed APK

Tags: android, proguard, apk

I have been trying from last 2 days to generate the secure signed apk for my application but still not get any success in it.

I have check so many answers of StackOverflow and tried every solution but nothing worked for me. 
So here i am if anyone can help me out it will be really grateful and will really appreciate the help.

Below is the error which i am getting while generating the Secure signed apk.

**EDITED:**

I have some changes in my proguard file and now i am getting below error

> ```
>   Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
> Note: there were 209 duplicate class definitions.
> You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
> Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
> Class       = [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl]
> Method      = [newAccessiblityDelegateBridge(Landroid/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat;)Ljava/lang/Object;]
> Instruction = [18] areturn
>  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find any super classes of [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1] (not even immediate super class [android/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate]))
>  Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
>  Class       = [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl]
>  Method      = [newAccessiblityDelegateBridge(Landroid/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat;)Ljava/lang/Object;]
>  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find any super classes of [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1] (not even immediate super class [android/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate]))
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find any super classes of [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1] (not even immediate super class [android/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate])
> at proguard.evaluation.value.ReferenceValue.generalize(ReferenceValue.java:287)
> at proguard.evaluation.value.ReferenceValue.generalize(ReferenceValue.java:481)
> at proguard.optimize.info.MethodOptimizationInfo.generalizeReturnValue(MethodOptimizationInfo.java:247)
> at proguard.optimize.evaluation.StoringInvocationUnit.generalizeMethodReturnValue(StoringInvocationUnit.java:195)
> at proguard.optimize.evaluation.StoringInvocationUnit.setMethodReturnValue(StoringInvocationUnit.java:126)
> at proguard.evaluation.BasicInvocationUnit.exitMethod(BasicInvocationUnit.java:134)
> at proguard.evaluation.Processor.visitSimpleInstruction(Processor.java:514)
> at proguard.classfile.instruction.SimpleInstruction.accept(SimpleInstruction.java:218)
> at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateSingleInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:753)
> at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:587)
> at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlockAndExceptionHandlers(PartialEvaluator.java:560)
> at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute0(PartialEvaluator.java:264)
> at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute(PartialEvaluator.java:181)
> at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
> at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:79)
> at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
> at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:91)
> at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
> at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:504)
> at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47)
> at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
> at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:116)
> at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:372)
> at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:306)
> at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:115)
> at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
> ```

Here is my UPDATED **Proguard.cfg** file

> ```
>  -optimizationpasses 9
>   -verbose
>   -dump class_files.txt
>   -printseeds seeds.txt
>   -printusage unused.txt
>   -printmapping mapping.txt
>   -allowaccessmodification
>   -keepattributes *Annotation*
>   -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
>   -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
>   -repackageclasses ''
>   -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
>   -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
>   -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
>   -dontpreverify
>   -dontwarn
>   -ignorewarnings
>
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
>   -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
>   -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
>   -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
>   -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
>   -dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
>
>   # Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
>   # is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
>   -keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
>       static final long serialVersionUID;
>       private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
>       private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
>       private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
>       java.lang.Object writeReplace();
>       java.lang.Object readResolve();
>   }
>
>   # Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
>   -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>       native <methods>;
>   }
>
>   -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>       public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
>   }
>
>   -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>       public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
>   }
>
>   # Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
>   # through introspection.
>   -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
>     public static <fields>;
>   }
>
>   # Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
>   -keepclassmembers enum * {
>       public static **[] values();
>       public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
>   }
>
>   -keep public class * {
>       public protected *;
>   }
>
>   -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
>     public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
>   }
>   ##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
>   ##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
>   # Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
>   # removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
>   -keepattributes Signature
>
>   # For using GSON @Expose annotation
>   # Gson specific classes
>   -keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
>   -keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
>   -keep class com.google.gson.FieldNamingStrategy { *; }
>   ##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
>   -keep class twitter4j.** { *; }
>   -keep class com.wli.ecard.TwitterShareActivity { *; }
>   -keep class com.wli.ecard.Vo.** { *; }
>   -keep class com.wli.ecard.EcardAcra.** { *; }
> ```

Please help me out any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html. Check the link

Comment: I have resolved my issue please check my answer posted below. Thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by adding the below two lines in my `proguard.cfg` file.

> -keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
>
>       -dontwarn android.support.v4.**

Comment: where are you?? Need help on this issue

Comment: @GrIsHu are In this proguard issue

Comment: when add external jar file to project.properties file and export it gives a error

Comment: Which jar files you are adding ? Just do not add that jars for being obfuscate.

Comment: i am using cordova 1.9.0 jar file and when add -libraryjars libs/cordova-1.9.0.jar like this error comes

Comment: Add the line in your proguard file `-libraryjars cordova-1.9.0` and then check.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45455/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-grishu)

Comment: In my case I have in cfg-file '-keep public class android.support.v4.** { ; }'. When I delete 'public' proguard not generate this error.

Comment: FYI, the `{* ; }` in the answer doesn't show the asterisk and looks like `{ ; }`

Answer (score 6):

use

```
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
```

**another try:**

download the lates proguard ( i downloaded 4.9) and changes the lib folder

**another another try:**

you can use a standard proguard. for example see [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg?r=877)

Recently I also faced several problems and planning to learn progruard mechanismn in depth. But at present I have very little idea about this. But the previous three solution saves me several time